# Directed acyclic graphs in regression model

Tags: model-selection, dag

I am using DAGs to select best set of variables for my logistic regression analysis.

Assessment of DAG includes one exposure, number of covariates and an outcome variable.

I have not found any solid statement how should I treat these terms with regard to logistic regression. I have several exposures of interest and several other covariates. Aren't all variables in regression analysis "equal"?

Lets say I have exposures X1 and X2 and covariates C1 and C2. When I perform logistic regression I get regressions coefficients for all these variables. Any covariate can shown significant effect in the model. Thats why I think them "equal".

If I want to assess the suitability of my model,should I use DAGs having both exposures as exposure of interest in two separate DAGs treating other exposure as covariate?

DAG 1: exposure of interest X1, covarites C1 and C2,other exposure X2 as covariate C3

DAG 2: exposure of interest X2, covarites C1 and C2,other exposure X1 as covariate C3

Comment: *Any covariate can shown significant effect in the model. Thats why I think them "equal".* Isn't this true for linear regression as well? Every independent variable in linear regression gives a p-value as well and can be significant. The fact that it's logistics regression should not change how you see the causal mechanism.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I agree. I refer to logistic regression only because I use it in my current data. ANY regression, would be more appropriate.  I am also applying log-binomial regression which is again the same thing with regard to this matter..